# Storing the result of an executable in a variable using a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have the command below that is supposed to loop through each line in filelist.txt, store the result of the executable in temp.txt and then set IDCH to the single line in temp.txt

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d:\fetchdoc\filelist.txt) do (
    D:\fetchdoc\filehdr.exe %%A 3 > temp.txt
    set /p IDCH=<temp.txt
    echo %IDCH%
    del temp.txt
)
```

This is what I get back for each loop with echo on:

```
D:\fetchdoc\images\export>(
D:\fetchdoc\filehdr.exe 142120_1 3  1>temp.txt
set /p IDCH= 0<temp.txt
echo
del temp.txt
)
ECHO is on.
```

For some reason, there is a problem when it tries to set the IDCH variable.  When I try to echo the variable, I get nothing.

Comment: I think you need to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `!IDCH!` since you're setting it within the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using a temp file, taking the result of your binary execution and storeing directly in variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d:\fetchdoc\filelist.txt) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%x in ('D:\fetchdoc\filehdr.exe "%%A" 3') do set IDCH=%%x
    echo !IDCH!
)
```

Comment: I think the !IDCH! vs. %IDCH% was what was really tripping me up.  Thanks everyone!